# Can't get rack-cors working in rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rack, cors

I wanted to implement CORS in my rails application, so I googled [rack-cors](https://github.com/cyu/rack-cors) gem for it. And I did everything as was said in README, that is updated Gemfile accordingly and updated `application.rb` like this:

```
module YourApp
  class Application < Rails::Application

    # ...

    config.middleware.use Rack::Cors do
      allow do
        origins '*'
        resource '*', :headers => :any, :methods => [:get, :post, :options]
      end
    end

  end
end
```

But it didn't work. No matter what I did, in the browser console I kept getting message:
`XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://somewebsite.com. Origin http://0.0.0.0:3000 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.`

After reading this [blogpost](http://www.dougwaltman.com/blog/getting-cors-working-in-ruby-on-rails) and [issue](https://github.com/cyu/rack-cors/issues/23) on github, I realized that maybe position of rack-cors middleware in the middleware stack matters. So I did as was told in the github issue:

```
module YourApp
  class Application < Rails::Application

    # ...

    config.middleware.insert 0, Rack::Cors do
      allow do
        origins '*'
        resource '*', :headers => :any, :methods => [:get, :post, :options]
      end
    end

  end
end
```

After that, when I run `rake middleware` rack-cors is really at the top of the stack.
But It still just simply won't work. I keep getting the same error. Anyone, please help.

Comment: I know it's obvious, but did you make sure to restart the rails server? Since this is part of initialization it won't take effect until a restart.

Comment: Yes, I restarted the server lots of times.

Comment: The problem is that it is not anything supernatural, just to get this gem working. Just driving me insane...

Comment: _After reading this blogpost_ link changed, is now at http://www.dougwaltman.com/blog/2013/getting-cors-working-in-ruby-on-rails

Comment: I ran into this issue with Rails 4.2.4, and fixed it by making sure `origins '*'` is set, as well as adding Rack::Cors with `insert_before 0`, as well as adding routes for OPTIONS calls, like this: `match 'users', to: 'users#index', via: [:options]` on top of the regular routes

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I ran into the same problem with heroku.  I found [this blog](http://singlebrook.com/blog/cloudfront-cdn-with-rails-on-heroku) with the same rack-cors issue.

Just moved the `use Rack::Cors` to `config.ru`, redeployed to heroku and it works.

```
require ::File.expand_path('../config/environment',  __FILE__)
run Rails.application

require 'rack/cors'
use Rack::Cors do

  # allow all origins in development
  allow do
    origins '*'
    resource '*', 
        :headers => :any, 
        :methods => [:get, :post, :delete, :put, :options]
  end
end
```

Comment: That **DO** work. And as of july 7th 2014, that's **the very only way** to make it work (or you can spend 2/3 hours landing on every solution available on google…). thx

Comment: make sure you have this `require 'rack/cors'`

Comment: This works great but it doesn't seem to work on development(for our app at least) So make sure you test it out on staging or other production like server if it doesn't work on development for you either.

Comment: 2021 and this is still the solution for a heroku Rails API with React SPA app.

Answer (score 13):

There is a new [issue](https://github.com/cyu/rack-cors/issues/32) thread for the heroku solution

Instead of using

```
config.middleware.use Rack::Cors do
```

try

```
config.middleware.insert_before ActionDispatch::Static, Rack::Cors do
```

That worked for me.

Comment: This seems to be a Rails version thing. I found I had to use the first code snippet in the answer above in Rails 3.2 and the second snippet in Rails 4.1.

Comment: both worked for me, rails 4.1. This thread is priceless, compared to the tons of crap that can be found about this topic on the web

Answer (score 3):

**Here's how I fixed mine:**

You just need to un-comment the Rack CORS gem in your Gemfile (if it's there) or just add it:

```
gem 'rack-cors'
```

And then run the code below to install the gem:

```
bundle install
```

Create a `config/initializers/cors.rb` file and put the code below into it:

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.insert_before 0, Rack::Cors do
  allow do
    origins '*'
    resource '*', headers: :any, methods: [:get, :post, :patch, :put]
  end
end
```

OR

Put the code below in `config/application.rb` of your Rails application. For example, this will allow GET, POST or OPTIONS requests from any origin on any resource:

```
module YourApp
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # ...
    
    # For Rails 5 Appications

    config.middleware.insert_before 0, Rack::Cors do
      allow do
        origins '*'
        resource '*', headers: :any, methods: [:get, :post, :options]
      end
    end

    # For Rails 3/4 Applications

    config.middleware.insert_before 0, "Rack::Cors" do
      allow do
        origins '*'
        resource '*', headers: :any, methods: [:get, :post, :options]
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Setting origins to '*' should be alright for development, but keep in mind that if you deploy to production you’ll want to change this value to match your front-end’s URI for security reasons.

**Note:** If you're running Rails, updating in `config/application.rb` or 'config/initializers/cors.rb` should be enough. There is no need to update config.ru as well.

**Reference**: [rack-cors](https://github.com/cyu/rack-cors)

Answer (score 2):

I had to create a special route to handle the options requests, the cors gem didn't do it for me like I expected it to. The route I added to the end of routes.rb was:

```
  match "*path", :to => proc {|env| [200, {
  'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' => '*',
  'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' => 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS',
  'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' => 'true',
  'Access-Control-Request-Method' => '*',
  'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' => 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization',
'Content-Type' => 'text/plain'

 }, ["CORS Preflight"]] }, :via => [:options]
```

Comment: This was the only solution that worked for me with rails 3.0 and ruby 1.8. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After all it came out that this gem has some issues with heroku, on the local machine it works perfectly fine.

Comment: Can you provide any further elaboration or links? Did you find a work around?

Answer (score -2):

Make sure you added or uncommented `gem 'rack-cors'` in the Gemfile

Comment: this is too obvious