# Rails. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angular

Error: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Backund Ruby on Rails, Frond-end Angular 5.

application.rb

```
...
module Dkeeper
  class Application < Rails::Application
    config.middleware.use Rack::Cors do
      allow do
      origins '*'
      resource '*', headers: :any, methods: [:get, :post, :put, :patch, :delete, :options, :head]
    end
end
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're missing insert_before 0 according to the [docs](https://github.com/cyu/rack-cors#configuration)

```
config.middleware.insert_before 0, Rack::Cors do
  allow do
    origins '*'
    resource '*', headers: :any, methods: [:get, :post, :options]
  end
end
```

Comment: When I use insert_before 0, I get an error another character, or rather the page code.

Comment: Here such, only it abbreviated.

     Error: Uncaught (in promise): <!DOCTYPE html>
     <html lang="en">
     <head>
       <meta charset="utf-8" />
       <title>Action Controller: Exception caught</title>
       <style>

Comment: Any other hints in the error, maybe in the rails console? Are you able to see the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response when you open up dev tools and check out network requests?

Comment: The browser console has:
Request URL: https://*.herokuapp.com/api/users
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 500 Internal Server Error
Remote Address: *******
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
...

On the local server, I have everything working, the problem is when I upload to Heroku.

Comment: By the way, you are right, the header is back, but still, what do I do with this new error, why do I get the application code?

Comment: Can you run `heroku logs --tail` and make the request to see if any server side errors show up?

Comment: It might be an order thing can you verify that `bundle exec rake middleware` is the same on local and heroku? https://stackoverflow.com/a/20465250/9430067 seems to move the config to config.ru, not sure if that would help but might be worth trying.

Comment: Logs during registration - 2018-07-13T11: 48: 24.637290 + 00: 00 heroku [router]: at = info method = POST path = "/ api / users" host = *.herokuapp.com request_id = f249ad32 -95f7-4a83-b0f4-d0f40cef16cc fwd = "176.98.73.167" dyno = web.1 connect = 1ms service = 480ms status = 500 bytes = 103602 protocol = https, and your team did not help.

Comment: any difference in ordering between `bundle exec rake middleware` and `heroku run rake middleware`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174942/discussion-between-andrea2010-and-dan-hilton).