# Rails assets Cloudfront fontawesome CORS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cors, font-awesome, amazon-cloudfront

I tried a lot of solutions found on stackoverflow/github for this issue but I can't get it to work.

I'm using [font-awesome-rails](https://github.com/bokmann/font-awesome-rails) and I precompile my assets for production.
I've set CloudFront for my assets in my production config:

```
config.action_controller.asset_host = "https://XXXX.cloudfront.net"
```

When I load a page (from Chrome/Firefox because Safari is OK with CORS) I get this common error message :

```
Font from origin 'https://XXXX.cloudfront.net' has been blocked from loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://example.com' is therefore not allowed access.
```

---

I already tried to :

1. Add the [gem rack-cors](https://github.com/cyu/rack-cors) and [change my config.ru](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20464939/1805275) without success
2. Set an `after_filter` to [set the server headers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15425988/1805275) without success
3. [Create an invalidation on CloudFront](http://blog.xdite.net/posts/2013/07/22/font-awesome-firefox-cloudfront) for the three fontawesome files without success

---

A workaround would be to remove the fontawesome gem and use instead:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css", :media => "all" %>
```

But I'd rather find the issue.

Thanks

Comment: Might need to add a CORS configuration on the AWS S3 bucket.

Answer (score 5):

I have had this issue and it was solved by doing the following changes. First of all, set a header on your http server 
`add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;`

the complete configuration used:

```
location ~* \.(ttf|ttc|otf|eot|woff|woff2|svg|font.css)$ {
  add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
  expires max;
  allow all;
  access_log off;
  add_header Cache-Control "public";
}
```

and then create the invalidation on Cloudfront.

ps: I did not use rack-cors or any other gem

Comment: Where we should put this code into? To production.rb? or initializer?

Comment: @Shalafister's these are nginx web server configurations.

Comment: Thanks for this. What would really put this answer over the top is an explanation of each line. I'm not sure if all of those (other than  `add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *`) are required to achieve the goal.

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me:

Your Bucket > Permissions > CORS Configuration and paste the following configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
    <AllowedHeader>Authorization</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

On your Rails project:

`> vim environments/production.rb`

add:

```
if ENV['CLOUDFRONT_ENDPOINT']
    config.action_controller.asset_host = proc { |source|
      if source =~ /^.*?\.(eot|ttf|woff|svg|otf)$/
        '//mydomain.com'
      else
        ENV.fetch('CLOUDFRONT_ENDPOINT') { 'https://cloudfrontname3244d4.cloudfront.net' }
      end
    }
end
```